# how to replace the array elements using array slice and splice?

Tags: php, arrays

how come am not able to replace the array elements with this simple code snippet of mine?

```
<?php

$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$replace = array_slice($input, -2, 2,true);


echo "<pre>",print_r(array_splice($input, 0, 2,$replace)),"</pre>";

?>
```

the output was like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
1
```

am expecting it to be

```
Array
(
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$result = array_slice($input, -2, 2, TRUE);

var_dump($result);
```

It's already enough ([Demo](http://codepad.org/xRX5vRBz)):

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
```

[`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) works similar for arrays like [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) works for strings.

Answer (score 2):

According to PHP's documentation for `array_splice`:

> Returns the array consisting of the **extracted** elements.

You are trying to print elements which were removed by splice and those are 2 elements starting from index 0 - therefore `a` and `b`.

`array_splice` modifies the original array, so you need to print it instead...

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$replace = array_slice($input, -2, 2,true);

array_splice($input, 0, 2,$replace);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($input);
echo "</pre>";
```

It's because the original array is modified, so you can't print the returnvalue of the slice function.